# How do I get Gallio.echo to run MbUnit Tests?

Tags: mbunit, gallio

I have MbUnit tests that run if I load them into MbUnit.GUI.exe, however when I try to execute them from the Gallio.echo command-line tool I get 0 test available.  I then loaded the assemblies into the Gallio GUI and the tests do not show.  I am missing something with the Gallio set-up and the documentation is lacking to put it mildly.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you
- Bruce

Comment: What command line are you using to run Echo?

Comment: I have tried many combinations, here is the most recent. 
Gallio.echo /r:Local /rd:C:\Gallio /rv:c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5 C:\src\build\bin\Test\testing.dll /rt:Text /rnf:test-{0} 
Gallio Echo - Version 3.1 build 397 Get the latest version at gallio.org Results 
Start time: 10:33 AM 
Initializing the runtime and loading plugins. 
[snip] 
Stop time: 10:33 AM (Total execution time: 4.642 seconds) 
0 run, 0 passed, 0 failed, 0 inconclusive, 0 skipped

When I exchange "Local" for" IsolatedProcess" I get a .NET Framework Initialization error –

Comment: Mmh... It seems correct. Perhaps something is broken with the install. Could you please try running Gallio.Utility.exe with the option "/verifyinstallation"? Meanwhile, maybe Jeff has some insight?

Comment: verify error: Plugin 'Gallio.VisualStudio.Tip90' contains file 'Gallio.VisualStudio.Tip90.Proxy.dll' but it does not exist.

I have un-installed and re-installed and the file still does not get extracted.  I extracted the missing file from the MSI package and the error goes away. 
I am now get error: Plugin 'Gallio.VisualStudio.Shell' is disabled: The plugin enable condition was not satisfied: '${process:DEVENV.EXE} or ${process
:VSTESTHOST.EXE} or ${process:QTAGENT.EXE} or ${process:QTAGENT32.EXE} or ${process:QTDCAGENT.EXE} or ${process:QTDCAGENT32.EXE}'.
'
Is the installation stable?

Comment: Personnally, I've been using Gallio for months (mainly Echo, the PowerShell snap-in, and in Visual Studio through TD.Net and Resharper) without any problem; both at work for production releases and at home for personal projects. The installation is very stable (and I'm using v3.2 daily builds)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your MbUnit v2 tests are compiled with the same version of MbUnit v2 as is distributed with Gallio.  It should also work with any sufficiently recent MbUnit v2.4.2 build downloaded from the site.

Comment: Thank You! When I was given this task I downloaded the latest Gallio and MbUnit installations, however the older MbUnit had been checked in with the source and was referenced there.  I updated the source with the latest and now the command-line doesn't error out.

Comment: I knew Jeff would have insight :p