# MbUnit under Linux, used within an F# project?

Tags: ubuntu, f#, mono, mbunit, gallio

<sub>*I tried asking this on the gallio-users list, but the question failed to appear (Google Groups says the post was successful). I suppose the list might be moderated by someone who does not read his email very often :-) Seeing as SO has tags for both Gallio and MbUnit, I thought it was worth asking here.*</sub>

I see the `MbUnit` front page mentions that they are keen on maintaining Mono-compatibility. There is also a >1-year [old post on gallio-users](https://groups.google.com/group/gallio-user/browse_thread/thread/6cd88aef65f4d3c2) saying that it does not work under Linux

The project I want to test compiles fine under Mono if I remove the `Parallelizable` attribute. I can launch the `Gallio` control panel under Linux, but not Icarus or Echo.

Is there any way of running `MbUnit` tests under Linux? Something that uses the command line (like `Gallio.Echo`) and does not need Monodevelop would be especially helpful.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of thoughts here since there isn't much online and this project is on hiatus apparently with likely no support for Mono compatibility coming anytime soon.

1) Not sure what version or build you have of Gallio, but you may try the Gallio bundle nuget from here and see if you get different results with this version: https://www.nuget.org/packages/GallioBundle/3.4.14. See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21185517/9798633

2) Make sure your tests are compiled with the same version of MbUnit as was distributed with Gallio, as discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2242849/9798633

3) If you try running in VS in a VM, doublecheck to make sure you have a Class Library project with references to both Gallio.dll and MbUnit.dll as mentioned here in "ASP.NET MVC 4 in Action":

ftp://soporte.uson.mx/PUBLICO/02_ING.SISTEMAS.DE.INFORMACION/PVI/ASP.NET%20MVC%204%20in%20Action.pdf